# Apache mod_rewrite never rewrite for existing directory except directory is certain directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

A website http://www.example.com/ runs on a CMS and everything goes through it by rules set in .htaccess. When visiting http://www.example.com/ the user is redirected to one of the following paths depending on the user's language settings:

```
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/fr/
```

The `/en/` and `/fr/` directories don't really exist, they are processed by the CMS.

I am adding a new section (`investors/`) to the site but don't want it to go through the CMS for now, but I don't want the users to notice it.

The original .htaccess file has these lines:

```
# never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# rewrite everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I managed to make it not go through the CMS if the requested path begins with `/en/investors/` or `/fr/investors/`:

```
# never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# rewrite everything else to index.php
# except investors' section
RewriteRule ^(?!\/en\/investors|\/fr\/investors).+ index.php [L]
```

I uploaded my `/en/investors/` and `/fr/investors/` directories onto the server and they work fine, but now the home page is broken because the `/en/` and `/fr/` directories now exist. How can I add exceptions to that rule?

Answer (score 0):

Simple add another rule to cover the 2 directories e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/?$ index.php [L]
```